# Find all x-ref with specific argument with IdaPython

Tags: ida, idapython

I have a function at `0xabcd` that is called a few times like `Func(1,2,3)` and `Func(4,4,5)`.

I want to find all the references where the third argument is `5`.

```
import idautils
for f in list(idautils.XrefsTo(0xabcd)):
```

How can I get the third argument from all the x-ref with IDAPython?

Answer (score 1):

As currently stated, there's no simple solution to such a general problem.

[Static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) is quite a complex subject and there are no generic solutions that are available out of the box.

A few basic examples of why this may be difficult are these:

1. Consider the case where the third argument to `Func` is a *user supplied input*. It is therefore *impossible* to know the value statically.
2. Moreover, a value may be derived from other external sources (the OS, the internet, etc).
3. Even when limiting to static programs, the code manipulating the variable before passing it on to `Func` may be complex and difficult to follow.

A *naïve* static solution may be a more viable solution. For example, a solution that assumes the third argument to `Func` is a hardcoded immediate value and not a variable, will require only little static analysis and can be achieved, although IDA is not best-suited for such tasks (I'd recommend you take a look at [angr](https://angr.io/) instead)

Alternatively, one might argue that *debugging* is a better solution, placing a break point on `Func` and parsing the arguments at call-time. This is again not IDA's forte but nowadays IDA's debugger is good enough to use for such a task.